# Remove # Hash from URL in React with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to remove the # Hash from the url using React Router dom.
I came across the solution of putting the browserrouter around the switch with the routes, which seems to only work when you change between tabs, but when reloading or loading the site initially the # still appears

My Router Code

```
return (
<BrowserRouter>
<Switch>
  {!authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
    <Route
      exact
      path="/"
      component={() => (
            <Home />
      )}
    />
  )}
  {!authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
    <Route path="/Login" component={() => <Login />} />
  )}
  {authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
    <Route
      path="/EmployeeHome"
      component={() => (
          <EmployeeHome />
      )}
    />
  )}
  {authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
    <Route path="/Appointment">
      <Redirect to="/EmployeeHome" />
    </Route>
  )}
  {authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
    <Route path="/Documentations" component={() => <Documentations />} />
  )}
  {authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
    <Route
      path="/Statistic"
      component={() => (
          <Statistics />
      )}
    />
  )}

  <Route path="*">
    {authCtx.isLoggedIn && <Redirect to="/Appointment" />}
    {!authCtx.isLoggedIn && <Redirect to="/" />}
  </Route>
</Switch>
</BrowserRouter>);
```

Comment: What version are you using? I haven't seen hashes in a React app for years.

Comment: Using ^16.0.0. Can I just upgrade it?

Comment: Is your app using a `HashRouter`? If so, then don't use a `HashRouter`, use one of the other high-level routers, e.g. `BrowserRouter`. Also, if you are using more than one router, don't. You really only need one router near the root of your app to provide a routing context for all routing/navigation components/hooks/etc... Remove all extraneous routers. You're using RRDv5 it seems, which allows you to nest routers, but it isn't recommended, and actually throws an invariant error in later version. Can you update your question to include *all* relevant routing & navigation code?

Comment: @isherwood nothing wrong with using hashrouter. Definitely preferred in situations where it's hard to do server-side url rewriting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was that I was using a **HashRouter**
and also a react-router-dom version `<=6.0`. I updated everything and changed to the v6 of the react-router-dom and used the **BrowserRouter** instead and now it works.

Here is my Code:

React Router

```
<Routes>
  {!authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
    <Route
      exact
      path="/"
      element={
            <Home />
      }
    />
  )}
  {!authCtx.isLoggedIn && <Route path="/Login" exact element={<Login />} />}
  {authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
    <Route
      exact
      path="/EmployeeHome"
      element={
          <EmployeeHome />
      }
    />
  )}
  {authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
    <Route
      exact
      path="/Documentations"
      element={ <Documentations />}
    />
  )}
  {authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
    <Route
      exact
      path="/Statistic"
      element={
          <Statistics />
      }
    />
  )}
  {authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/EmployeeHome" />} />
  )}
  {!authCtx.isLoggedIn && <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />}
</Routes>
```

Index.js

```
const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName("base") 
[0].getAttribute("href");
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl}>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
rootElement
);
```

Comment: You can also use different `routes` instances for sections like `#Home` or just by short some text from `url` browser bar.

Answer (score 4):

```js
if(window.location.hash) {
     window.history.replaceState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
}
```

**Before**

`site.url/home#section`

**After**

`site.url/home`

Answer (score 1):

I mean you can interpret "is working now" as a favourable way to you, but indeed, these are different oriented instances from **React** components:

[`<HashRouter>`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter)

*A `<Router>` that uses the hash portion of the URL (i.e. window.location.hash) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.*

```
const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName("base") 
[0].getAttribute("href");
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
  <HashRouter
    basename={baseUrl}
    getUserConfirmation={optionalFunc}
    hashType={optionalString}>
    <App />
  </HashRouter>,
rootElement
);
```

[`<BrowserRouter>`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter)

*A `<Router>` that uses the **HTML5** history **API** (pushState, replaceState and the popstate event) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.*

```
const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName("base") 
[0].getAttribute("href");
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter
  basename={baseUrl}
  forceRefresh={optionalBool}
  getUserConfirmation={optionalFunc}
  keyLength={optionalNumber}>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>,
rootElement
);
```

Answer (score 0):

From all of the above the simplest solution is to navigate back to #, like this

`navigate('#');`

This way it won't change your URL and query params and it will allow you to reset the hash.

NB make sure to use `useNavigate` from `react-router-dom` in order to use the navigate function